# How to Reach the Custom Errors page in ASP.NET when Session State Provider is Down?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I am trying to show a customer errors page in ASP.NET when the database is down. I use the SQL Server mode to hold the session data. The problem is that the custom errors page is never called.

Since the session data and the database are on the same server, this does not redirect to the custom error page? I’m guessing the web application has not loaded at this point?.  The user is presented with the stack trace for the session state connection failure.

It seems that we need something that sits in front of the initial website load to check connectivity to the database. Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: Can you provide what you have right now on your web.config?

Comment: <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On"/>

Comment: Maybe this can shed some light http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages

Answer (score 1):

Add something like this to your web.config?

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

You can read more information [here](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages)

If it is your SqlSessionState that is failing, you should handle the corresponding error in the `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax`

You can read more information [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355)

Comment: How do I know the statusCode when the DB is down?

Comment: Also it doesnt hit the debug point if I place any inside the Application_Error event?

Comment: If you dont specify a status code you get pushed to the default redirect.

Comment: I believe the problem is that IIS tries to load the application, but because the Session State Provider fails on connection to the database, it's perceived as a configuration error in the web.config file, and not an application error. See my answer :)

Comment: In that case, you should be handling the `Application_Error` event in `Global.asax`

Comment: @FlyingStreudel No that isn't correct, it isn't an application error, it's a configuration error - the application isn't run, it's a module that is being initialized that causes the error. Global.asax doesn't come into play. See my comment about using an Http Module on the original post.

Comment: @jamiebarrow - AFAIK you can't catch configuration errors. They are thrown by the CLR, not your application at the time the web.config is read. If you are getting config errors as a result of initializing your state provider, you will need to change your approach. The web.config should always be successful if you want any of your app code to run.

Comment: I was hoping that using IIS7 with integrated pipeline would allow one to catch the error by using an Http Module. I did try creating two custom modules, one throwing ConfigurationException in Init(), both handling Error event, and neither of their event handlers fired. It seems that your thoughts are correct though, you can't handle the 'config' error as a result of initialization. Pity that is how the Microsoft AppFabric Cache Session State Provider works :( Guess a wrapper approach is necessary, which shields the exception some way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is coming from the fact that because you're using an out of memory session state provider (being the database), and the database connection has a failure, then there is actually a perceived error in the web configuration (not in the application). I have a similar problem, where I'm using AppFabric Cache for my session state provider, but when the AppFabric Cache Service is down, I get the Configuration Error page.

Because of this, you can't use the customErrors solution as FlyingStreudel has already suggested, since it isn't an error in your application, but rather in the loading of the configuration.

I've looked around for a way to solve this, but couldn't find any. I hope this question gets answered, it's got me confused already with the various error configuration options...

**Update:** After investigating this for a while now, it appears that my issue comes from the fact that the SessionStateModule causes the AppFabric cache session state provider to try and connect to the DataCache (which is not available), and an exception (probably timeout) is thrown somewhere. **Because this happens in the Init of the HTTP module, there seems to be no way around the yellow screen of death**.

I wouldn't be surprised if the original poster's problem is the same - the connection to the SQL server occurring in the initialization of the SessionStateModule.

Comment: I think maybe the answer is to write a custom Http Module [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx ]

Comment: Or maybe not, seeing as the execution order of modules is apparently not predictable [ http://forums.asp.net/t/1101427.aspx/1?HttpModule+execute+order ]

Comment: "For each event, event handlers for each module are executed in the order in which modules are configured in the <modules> configuration section. Global.asax event handlers are executed last." [ http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/381/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis-70/ ]

Answer (score 0):

Because the error page is an ASP.NET Page ( I can see this from your comment), It will hit the session database in page life cycle. 
You have to set below directive on Error.aspx Page to tell ASP.Net not to load session information for it:

```
EnableSessionState="false"
```

Please note this will only work if you are not using any session information in the error page.

Additionally, I also managed Global.asax page as below :

```
    private static Exception startException;
     protected void Application_Start()
            {
                try
                {
                    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
                    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
                    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new MyDateTimeModelBinder());

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    startException = ex;
                }
            }
  static HashSet<string> allowedExtensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    ".js", ".css", ".png",".jpg",".jpeg",".gif",".bmp"
};

        public bool IsStaticFile(HttpRequest request)
     {  //My project was a mix of asp.net web forms & mvc so had to write this      
                if (Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/bundles/") || Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/frontendcss?") ||
                     Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains("/fonts/") 
//these are my css & js bundles. a bit of hack but works for me.
                     )
                {
                return true;
            }
            string fileOnDisk = request.PhysicalPath;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileOnDisk))
            {
                return false;
            }

            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileOnDisk).ToLower();

            return allowedExtensions.Contains(extension);
        }
     protected void Application_BeginRequest()
            {
                if (startException != null && Request.RawUrl.ToLower() == "/Error.aspx".ToLower())
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (startException != null && IsStaticFile(Request))
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (startException != null && Request.RawUrl.ToLower()!= "/Error.aspx".ToLower())
                {
                    //Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
                    Server.Transfer("Error.aspx");
                    this.Context.AddError(startException);                
                    return;
                }


            }
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                   Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
                     Response.Clear();
                    Server.ClearError(); 
                   Server.Transfer("Error.aspx");     
                }
```